# How can I look at modules using SonarQube 7.7?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I've been previously using SonarQube 6.7 but got it now upgraded to version 7.7.

As stated in [SonarQube 7.6 release notes](https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-7-6/):

> Tracking code quality is as easy as following your project structure.
>   **SonarQube 7.6 drops the concept of modules and keeps things simple
>   with your file directory layout.** With the refreshed Measures Page it’s
>   easier than ever to discover quality issues.

The problem is that with the change for directory layout, it's no longer possible to drill down to details of specific modules of my application. Being technically responsible for a large system (over 300K lines) with distributed development teams, looking at the details of each component was particularly important to see their evolution and follow up with the teams responsible for each of those modules, but I cannot find a good way to do it anymore.

I'm not only talking about the UI here, but also about the Web API that I use to generate reports. For example, using `&qualifiers=BRC` in the query string to retrieve sub-projects is no longer returning anything.

So, any way to obtain the old behaviour? A plugin perhaps?